# CSS 1. Как можно полностью обновить страницу. 2. Как выровнять текст вертикально?

Tags: css, текст, выравнивание, обновление

1. При изменении чего-либо в коде, естественно, нужно обновить страницу. Обычный F5 или же Ctrl + F5 не всегда помогают.
   Как можно полностью обновить страницу?
2. Как выровнять текст вертикально?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас на скриншотах css код, который потом в итоге на поздних этапах разработки загонит в вас не то, что в угол, а в **бездну**, из которой вы не сможете выбраться, не переписав все полностью!

1. Не используйте идентификаторы `#`. Применяйте стили только для классов, например `.header{}`. Вес идентификаторов выше классов. Вы не сможете потом переопределить стили из идентификатора классом, не прибегнув к различным нехорошим практикам!
2. Не увлекайтесь вложением элементов `header #logo img{}` без необходимости. Так вы задаете селектору слишком большой вес, который потом не сможете переопределить, не написав потом схожую конструкцию. Сами подумайте, для чего вы описали такую тройную вложенность?
3. Не группируйте элементы через запятую, даже если у них вроде как одинаковый стиль по вашей задумке, особенно если элементы не связаны между собой в пределах какого-то блока на странице. Так вы задаете селектору опять же большой вес, который не сможете переопределить. Или захочется вам поменять цвет в одном блоке потом и не сможете, вот увидите.

Ответ не по теме, просто страшно стало за вас.
Почитайте, например, про [Вес селекторов](https://canonium.com/articles/css-understanding-weight-selectors) и [БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/), чтобы в целом было представление.

Answer (score 0):

> Как выровнять текст вертикально?

Пропустил

```
display: inline-block;
```

А ещё в font-family какой-то мусор.